# How do I return a reference to a control?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to return a reference to a checkbox, but the following code does not work as I expect.

```
Private Function ck() as Access.CheckBox
  ck = Me.ckExample
End Function
```

The full function takes parameters and has flow control to choose which control to return, but this is a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. This function errors out with the message

> Run-item error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

As far as I can tell it's attempting to set `ck` to the *value* of `Me.ckExample` rather than as a reference to the control, despite it being properly declared. I'm at a loss as to how to do this correctly. I've also attempted declaring it as `Control`, as well as assigning to a temporary variable declared with `Dim ckTemp as Access.CheckBox`.

Comment: Since it's an object, you need to use `Set ck = Me.ckExample`

Comment: If you posted more of the code we might be able to suggest a better solution to the wider problem

Comment: @CallumDA The purpose of a minimal example is to not distract from the root question with irrelevant details. Also why didn't you submit that as an answer @Erik? That's exactly what I was doing wrong.

Comment: On mobile, in meeting, hard to write an answer with proper formatting. Might do so later

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys that's exactly what you're doing wrong, *syntactically*, sure. But since I cannot fathom a valid reason to have a `Private` function that returns a public member that's already on the interface, surely there's more to it.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys, thank you for the explanation >.< . I've been here long enough to understand MCV. I offered to look at more code because it's not often you see functions written for this purpose, I get a hunch you've got a wider problem and we're falling into [xy territory](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I was just offering to help.

Comment: Also @ErikvonAsmuth, if that's the only answer we get to on this question IMO it should be closed for basic syntax error rather than answered.

Comment: @CallumDA my mug approves this message. Let me dig through any one of the 800+ VBA questions that mention error 91....

Comment: @Mat'sMug "The full function takes parameters and has flow control to choose which control to return, but this is a minimal example to demonstrate the problem." The control to return is dependant upon the data in the current record.

Comment: I spent an hour searching for various descriptions of the issue, but not the phrase `Run time error '91'`. While I agree solution is a duplicate, I think it's frustrating that the next person to search for 'how do I return a reference' in some context will once again run into a brick wall.

Comment: Well, that's where duplicates come in. As long as you don't delete, future users can find the answer more easily